# using "dear " for men addressing each other

Tags: gender-politics

I think for women addressing each other as "dear" is acceptable..but man-man is that  awkard?

And also for men to women or vice versa ?

Edit

I mean speaking and when you call a member of the opposite gender "dear" is it similar to the word "darling" but slightly less serious?

Comment: Even between women, addressing someone as *dear* is very likely to be condescending if not downright caustic. For a man to use it with another man is likely to be an order of magnitude more pejorative. It could even be a prelude to a fist fight.

Comment: What is wrong with you?

Comment: It's a word that, in modern speech, is almost never used. The only time I ever use it is in the first line of a letter or e-mail (and even then, relatively rarely). And the only time I hear it is when someone's reading a letter aloud or absentmindedly says "oh, dear" because they've realized they made a mistake. Ironically enough, it has fallen out of favor as a term of endearment.

Comment: The most amusing usage of  'dear' from one man to another that I've heard was in the 1980s, when Brian Widlake, a senior British reporter (who at that time was the presenter of BBC Radio 4's news programme *The World at One*), had just posed a question to Robert Runcie (the Archbishop of Canterbury). When Runcie replied, Widlake came back with a point of his own in which he condescendingly addressed Runcie as 'my dear'. One of radio's golden moments...

Comment: @Erik Kowal Should it have been 'very dear' or 'right dear'?

Comment: @ErikKowal    From what I've seen in movies, it seems to me that working-class women from South London often use both "dear" and "darling"  when addressing one another. Am I right ?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Neither. 'Old dear'.

Comment: @Centaurus - Yes — at least when I still lived in England (till about 15 years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years ago it was much more common to hear women call each other "dear". It sounds antiquated now, and a bit condescending. (The same with men calling a woman under the age of 75 or so, "dear".) This is especially true on the NE and SW Coasts - where people are much more easily offended. (In other areas, (US) it is a bit more common.) Man to man, either expression ("dear" or, "darling") sounds bizarre, and may cause a physical altercation.

Within an intimate relationship, (man/woman, woman/woman, man/man) anything goes; and possibly from a child to an elderly parent you'd hear "dear" or "darling" more.

P.S. A man may refer to another man as his "dear friend", but it would be unusual (not unheard of) to address him as such.

In the Southern US, there is a custom where men may refer to *any* woman as "darling", (or, "darlin'") and women are very likely to say "darlin'" to a male or female of any age.

Comment: @Josh61, in our famously cool (UK) climate that's not true.  Some shop-assistants may still call me Sir, but mostly, informality rules.  I've gotten used to being called mate, pal, darling, luv, chief and many other local variants.

Comment: @DavidGarner - I am pleased to hear that :))

Answer (score 1):

in many languages (Slaviс f.e.) "dear" is often used in addressing within the same gender. It is used to demonstrate warm attitude to your friend.

Comment: Yes, it's true for many languages but I don't think I've heard two male acquaintances address each other with "dear". It is quite an effeminate way of greeting a man whom you barely know.

Comment: Then there's France ...I work in London, but a few years ago I visited the sister company in Paris, which involved LOTS of language preparation since I only have high-school French.  I wondered whether I should be using 'tu' [informal] or 'vous' [forma] to people who were colleagues, one country removed.  The question was answered when I realized that everyone in the Paris office used 'vous' *to each other*.